# How to run a computational solution for ELISA long-term projects in r using new data files?

Tags: r

I am new in R and I'm trying to run a code written by Feng et al., (2019). They already provide the code in their paper, and I prepared all the text files that are needed for it, but for some reason the code keeps running on the results the authors provide (the example data). I can't figure it out and I would appreciate any advise you can give me. Thanks for your time!
The code:

```
#get file folder
dir_file<-system.file("extdata", package="ELISAtools")
dir_file<-("C://Users//ElinD//OneDrive//Desktop//ELISAtools//extdata") 

#setwd(dir_file)
batches<-loadData(file.path(dir_file,"mytextfile2.txt"))
```

This is my data:

```
> dput(File)
structure(list(ExpID = c("Exp1", "Exp2", "Exp2", "Exp3"), FileName = c("plate1.txt", 
"plate2.txt", "plate3.txt", "plate4.txt"), Batch = c("Batch1", 
"Batch2", "Batch2", "Batch3"), Num_Plate = 1:4, Date = c("03/01/2024", 
"10/01/2024", "11/01/2024", "22/01/2024"), AnnotationFile = c("AnnotationfileVER4.txt", 
"AnnotationfileVER4.txt", "AnnotationfileVER4.txt", "AnnotationfileVER4.txt"
), Std_Conc = c("stdtextconc.txt", "stdtextconc.txt", "stdtextconc.txt", 
"stdtextconc.txt"), Dir_Annotation = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), Dir_StdConc = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Hi Elin - questions on Stack Overflow do much better if they are [minimal, reproducible and self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). At the moment this isn't reproducible or self-contained as you're loading data not in the question. Can you find a _minimal_ way of generating enough data to reproduce this error?

Comment: The numerous spelling errors in output generated by the code provided by the third party would make me cautious about its reliability…

Comment: Thank you. I hope I now the question is clearer. I think the problem has something to do with uploading the file into R. I really appreciate your help!